# Prove that the two polynomials intersect each other only at a single point

Tags: polynomials, binomial-theorem

Here are the polynomials:

$$D^K_1(\theta)=\sum_{i=\lceil{K/2}\rceil}^K \binom{K}{i}\theta^i(1-\theta)^{K-i}$$

and

$$D^K_2(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=\lceil{K/2}\rceil}^K \binom{K}{i}\left(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\right)^i\left(1-\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\right)^{K-i}$$

> **Question:** For every $K$ (odd) is it true that $D^K_1(\theta)$ intersects $D^K_2(\theta)$ only at a single point on $\theta\in(0,\,0.5)$?

Note: Second polynomial is a polynomial in $\theta/(1-\theta)$ thanks to GerryMyerson.

---

**My own work**: I worked on the problem and obtained the following:

> $D^K_1(0)=D^K_2(0)=0$ and $D^K_1(1/2)=D^K_2(1/2)=1/2$
>
> Both $D^K_1(\theta)$ and $D^K_2(\theta)$ are monotone increasing functions of $\theta$ on $0<\theta<1/2$ for all $K$.
>
> What remains to show is that $D^K_1(\theta)-D^K_2(\theta)$ is neither positive nor negative for all $0<\theta<1/2$ given a $K$

Namely, if two polynomials are increasing, starting and ending at the same points, either one is less or greater than the other at all points or it must intersect the other polynomial at a single point. Below, I give some figures for $K=3$, $K=5$ and $K=7$

**Added (29.09):** If I multiply both $D^K_1(\theta)$ and $D^K_2(\theta)$ by $2$, then they will be cumulative distribution functions of two different random variables $X$ and $Y$ on $[0,0.5]$. Then it will suffice to show that $X$ doesnt stochastically dominate $Y$ or vice versa.

**Added (29.09)_ver2:** I think there is a much easier way for the proof. Only two things are required.

$1$-$)$ For $\theta=0.45$ or some other number very close to $0.5$ but still less than that, $D^K_2(\theta)>D^K_1(\theta)\forall K$, it is obvious from the figures that red line is above the blue for all $\theta$ large enough in $(0,0.5)$

$2$-$)$ For $\theta=\epsilon$, namely keeping it as small as possible, in other words whenever $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ then $D^K_1(\theta)>D^K_2(\theta)\forall K$.

$1$-$)$ seems to be easy I guess but for $2$-$)$ I have currently no idea.

[image: The polynomials for K=3]

[image: The polynomials for K=5]

[image: The polynomials for K=7]

Comment: $D_2$ is *not* a polynomial.

Comment: @GerryMyerson how about Polynomial in $\theta/1-\theta$?

Comment: "What remains to show is that $D^K_1(\theta)−D^K_2(\theta)$ is neither positive nor negative for all $0<\theta<1/2$ given a $K$" Wait, what? calling the difference $f(\theta)$, and $\theta_0$ the point of intersection, then according to your graphs, $f(\theta)>0$ for $0<\theta<\theta_0$, and $f(\theta)<0$ for $1/2>\theta>\theta_0$

Comment: @roman yes that is what I am saying actually. The difference is neither negative nor positive **everywhere** on $(0,0.5)$ as you said.

Comment: Ok, i see. I parsed that wrong.

Comment: Write $\theta/(1-\theta)$ rather than $\theta/1-\theta$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Oh yeah. Fast writing results in such sometimes. Thx.

Comment: "Namely, if two polynomials are increasing, starting and ending at the same points, either one is less or greater than the other at all points or it must intersect the other polynomial at a single point. " this is not true at all, there can be any number of intersection points in that interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to your question #2 about showing that $D_{2}^{K}(\theta) < D_{1}^{K}(\theta)$ for all $K$ when $|\theta| < \epsilon$ is sufficiently small, I observe the following:

$$\lim_{|\theta| = \epsilon \to 0} \frac{D_{1}^{K}(\epsilon) - D_{2}^{K}(\epsilon)}{ \epsilon^{\lceil K/2 \rceil}} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \sum_{i=\lceil K/2 \rceil}^{K}\binom{K}{i}\epsilon^{i-\lceil K/2 \rceil} \left[ (1-\epsilon)^{K-i} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)^{i}}\left(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}\right)^{K-i}\right]\\
= \binom{K}{\lceil K/2 \rceil}\frac{1}{2} > 0$$

Thus, by continuity we have that for any $K$ there exists an $\epsilon_{K} > 0$ small enough such that $D_{1}^{K}(\theta) > D_{2}^{K}(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in (0, \epsilon_{K})$.